# width=device-width => fixed element problem

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, viewport

У меня в head правило `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`, а у `body min-width:400px`. Это сделано для того, чтобы на малых экранах просто масштабировалось всё, сохраняя пропорции. Но элементы с `position:fixed` почему-то вылазят. Вот на скрине корзина с товарами, у которой `right:-100vw` вылазит на экран, а когда размер экрана `>= 400px`, то всё нормально. Как с этим бороться?

[image: корзина поплыла ыыы]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получается что `100vw` примеряется к ширине экрана, а размер документа больше размера экрана (когда экран `<400px`), поэтому и вылазит. Но если поставить например `right:calc(-100vw - 400px)`, тогда в любом случае оно спрячется. Хотя в примере ниже я привязываю right к параметрам ширины блока, чтобы он выезжал более плавно, а не с разгону.

Насчет размера, потому что корзина будет меньше полной ширины, если `100vw`, то я просто использовал `min-width: 400px` для корзины и других выползающих окон.

Насчет высоты несколько сложнее, ведь поставив высоту `window.innerHeight` оно всё равно из-за масштаба будет меньше высоты реальной, которая нужна для полного заполнения. Поэтому я высчитываю пропорцию, и умножаю эту высоту, получая такую, которая какраз закрывает весь экран.

Такую функцию я вызываю в начале и когда window.onresize event. Возможно кому-то пригодится.

```
function window_resize_operations_with_blocks_func(){
    cart_block.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    see_block.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    if (see_block.style.right !== '0px'){
        see_block.style.right = see_block.clientWidth * (-1) + 'px';
    }
    if (cart_block.style.right !== '0px'){
        cart_block.style.right = cart_block.clientWidth * (-1) + 'px';
    }
    //а з висотою потяжче, бо мені треба дізнатися пропорції, щоб на основі них вивести висоту.
    if (window.innerWidth < 400){
        proportion = 400 / window.innerWidth;
        //+ 4px навсяк, шоб полоска знизу пропала.
        h = window.innerHeight * proportion + 4 + 'px';
        see_block.style.height = h;
        cart_block.style.height = h;
    }
}
```